# How to integrate Twitter in my App for Login and Tweet - Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am building an application in which I want to integrate Twitter. I have gone through several docs and links but still I am at the starting point.

I need two functionality for this app:

1. Login through Twitter account
2. Tweet through logged in account

I know that we can use `Twitter 4J library` for this but I don't know how to use this.

Also I would like to know whether I can get any response Id if a user tweets successfully.

I have already created my Twitter Test app and I have the Consumer Key, Consumer Secret Key. Please help me to sort out this.

Comment: Twitter has a fabric plugin for android studio that will help you in both the functionality. I need to mention that the plugin will give you necessary code too :)

Comment: you should switch to android studio.yet, you are not convinced visit this link -  [link](http://androidbinder.blogspot.in/2015/06/getting-started-with-android-studio-m.html) @SalmanKhan

Answer (score 0):

Use [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) for your requirement. Read out [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815900/Android-social-network-integration) for more details about ASNE.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter also released Fabric which is a set of tools like Crashylitics, Admob but also kits which include a SDK for integratting twitter in your app.

**Fabric Twitter kit** : https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter

**Installation instruction** : https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cant see any download link there. I am using Eclipse not Android Studio.

Comment: @SalmanKhan see updated answer. You should REALLY consider using Android Studio, no way I've working with Eclipse, Android Studio is really optimised for working on Android, making everything easy.

Answer (score 0):

i really recommend to take a look at this [example](https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android) from Twitter that demonstrate how to use Fabric kits on your android app, it shows you how to login with twitter account or digits, compose tweets, Search, Crashlytics...

for example, for login :

```
private void setUpTwitterButton() {
    twitterButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_button);
    twitterButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            SessionRecorder.recordSessionActive("Login: twitter account active", result.data);
            startThemeChooser();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.toast_twitter_signin_fail),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Crashlytics.logException(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the post the status to twitter from android application.

To answer your queries:

1. Login through Tweet- We will use OAuth protocol to integrate the twitter to android application
2. Tweet through logged in account- For this we will be using Twitter4J library and post the tweets from android application

Having said that,
We cannot post directly to twitter, so we have to use Async Task for it.
You can use following code for reference:

```
  new UseTweeter().execute(); // async task call

    public class UseTweeter extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pdProgressCircleSend=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pdProgressCircleSend.setMessage(Constants.POSTING_TWEET);
        pdProgressCircleSend.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        TweetThisMessage(); //Call for posting status
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if(pdProgressCircleSend!=null && pdProgressCircleSend.isShowing()) {
            pdProgressCircleSend.dismiss();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Tweeted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
    public void TweetThisMessage(){
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthAccessToken(accesstoken);
    builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accesstokensecret);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerkey);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumersecret);
    OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(builder.build());
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(auth);

    StatusUpdate status=new StatusUpdate(sTweet);
    status.setMedia(f);
    try{
        Log.i("TAGTweet","sTweet in TweetThisMessage is sTweet"+ sTweet);
        twitter.updateStatus(sTweet);
    }catch (TwitterException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```